# Google Calendar API: Unable to setAllowedConferenceSolutionTypes to include hangoutsMeet when creating event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Using the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), I am trying to create a new calendar event and attach a `hangoutsMeet` conference. When I attempt to do so, I receive an error stating `Invalid conference type value`.

Using the same code, I am able to create a new event and attach an `eventHangout` conference.

I understand why I am receiving the error: according to the API, my calendar only supports the `eventHangout` conference type.

**<<<< edit #1 on April 3 2020**

Clarification following [Andres Duarte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11352221/andres-duarte)'s answer: this only appears as a limitation when I attempt to create an event via the API. When I manually create an event using the Google Calendar interface, I **am** able to add a Google Meet. In fact, that's the only conferencing option that's displayed in the dropdown.

**>>>>**

My question is, **how can I update my calendar settings (with or without the API) such that I can use the API to create events with attached `hangoutsMeet` conferences**?

Here is some sample code to demonstrate what I've tried:

**<<<< edit #2 on April 3 2020**

Clarification following [hooman182](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6799268/hooman182)'s answer: I have updated my code sample to demonstrate that I am setting `requestId` correctly, using a string.

**>>>>**

```
try {


    // fetch the calendar
    $calendar = 'myCalendar';
    $calendarObject = $service->calendars->get($calendar);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "\nORIGINAL *******************************************************\n\n";
    var_dump($calendarObject->getConferenceProperties()->getAllowedConferenceSolutionTypes());


    // set the allowed conferences solutions type
    $calendarObject->getConferenceProperties()->setAllowedConferenceSolutionTypes(
        array(
            "hangoutsMeet",
            "eventHangout",
            "eventNamedHangout",
        )
    );
    echo "\nUPDATED *******************************************************\n\n";
    var_dump($calendarObject->getConferenceProperties()->getAllowedConferenceSolutionTypes());


    // save the changes to the calendar
    $calendarObject = $service->calendars->patch($calendar, $calendarObject);;
    echo "\nSAVED *********************************************************\n\n";
    var_dump($calendarObject->getConferenceProperties()->getAllowedConferenceSolutionTypes());


    // add a createRequest to my event
    $event->setConferenceData(new Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData(array(
        'createRequest' => array(
            'requestId' => md5(time()),
            'conferenceSolutionKey' => array(
                'type' => 'hangoutsMeet',
            )
        )
    )));


    // save the event
    $event = $service->events->insert($calendar, $event, array(
        'conferenceDataVersion' => 1
    ));


} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {

    echo "\nERRORS ********************************************************\n\n";
    var_dump($e->getErrors());
    die;

}
```

And here is the output of the above:

```
ORIGINAL *******************************************************

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "eventHangout"
}

UPDATED *******************************************************

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "hangoutsMeet"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "eventHangout"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "eventNamedHangout"
}

SAVED *********************************************************

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "eventHangout"
}

ERRORS ********************************************************

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["domain"]=>
    string(6) "global"
    ["reason"]=>
    string(7) "invalid"
    ["message"]=>
    string(30) "Invalid conference type value."
  }
}
```

Additional details:

- I am using a service account with domain wide delegation enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating the event you need to use the service account credentials to impersonate a user in your G Suite domain, this way you'll be able to create events with `hangoutsMeet` conference type, which is only available for G Suite users.

Even though you service account has domain-wide delegation it doesn't have the same privileges as a G Suite user, from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#differences_between_a_service_account_and_a_user_account):

> Service accounts are not members of your G Suite domain, unlike user
>   accounts.

In your case, that's why you'd able to create events only with `eventHangout` conference type, which is intended for consumers as stated in the documentation for the [event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) resource:

> The possible values are:
>
> "eventHangout" for Hangouts for consumers (http://hangouts.google.com)
>
> "eventNamedHangout" for classic Hangouts for G Suite users (http://hangouts.google.com)
>
> "hangoutsMeet" for Hangouts Meet (http://meet.google.com)
>
> "addOn" for 3P conference providers

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response! Unfortunately, this is not the issue: First, the `eventNamedHangout` type is also missing from the list produced by the `getAllowedConferenceSolutionTypes` method. Second, I **am** able to create Hangouts Meets when creating calendar events manually. I've updated my question to add this detail.

Comment: Hi, could you give more specifics about the calendar you're using? How did you create it? Who's the owner? With which account are you accessing to the Calendar UI? It looks like the problem it's related with the calendar itself because it's behaving as a consumer calendar and not a G Suite calendar. Also, are you impersonating a specific user when using the service account credentials?

Comment: the calendar was created via the API and it has several owners. I am using one of the owners to access the Calendar UI and create a new account with a Hangouts Meet. I am not impersonating a specific user when I use the service account credentials.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Impersonating a user on the G Suite domain does the trick, thank you! For anyone else who comes across this, you will need to 1) turn on domain-wide delegation, 2) authorize your service account's client id on your G Suite domain, 3) impersonate a user on your domain when using the service account to create an event.

Answer (score 1):

Appereantly you forgot to add requestID on your Request.

Resource : [Add video and phone conferences to events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#conferencing)

```
 "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "conferenceSolutionKey": {
        "type": "eventHangout"
      },
      "requestId": "yourcodehere"
    }
  }
```

> You can create a new conference for an event by providing a *createRequest* with a newly generated *requestId* which can be a random **string**. Conferences are created asynchronously, but you can always check the status of your request to let your users know what’s happening.

i hope this help.

Comment: nice catch -- however, even when I switch to using a string for `requestId`, I get the same error.

Comment: i try to break down your code to make me understand more:
first you call your calendar id from $service->calendars->get($calendar);
and patch with $service->calendars->patch($calendar, $calendarObject);
have you try to remove patch and just make event. 
https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events if you can make new event with this feature, its mean you ready to go.

Comment: hi @hooman182, the calendar patch is just to demonstrate that I'm unable to update the calendar. The error I receive (`Invalid conference type value.`) happens when I attempt to create an event: `$event = $service->events->insert($calendar, $event, array( 'conferenceDataVersion' => 1 ));`